# Making a comparison using "like" or "as"

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

> 1. I don't make wrong decisions, like Mary.
> 2. Like Mary, I don't make wrong decisions.

When we are comparing A and B, Is there is a difference between using **Like** before and after a negative clause?

Answer (score 1):

When we use *like* or *as* before a negative clause, this comparison refers to the whole clause.

> Like Mary, I don't make wrong decisions. *(Mary doesn't make wrong decisions.)*

Using *like* or *as* after a negative clause, refers to the positive part of the previous clause.

> I don't make wrong decisions, like Mary. *(Mary makes wrong decisions.)*

Comment: I've upvoted because *in the specific context under consideration* your "rule" seems credible enough. But actually I think the underlying principle is more like *By default, the referent of **like** in such constructions is **the nearest credible word or term** [in the utterance].* Applying that "rule" gives the same result for the example under consideration, but it can also be applied more generally to *any* such "adverbial" element. And although the specific example usually *wouldn't* be considered ambiguous, in principle it is (especially since the comma steers towards "sentence adverb").

Comment: I think the second sentence would really need to end "like Mary *does*" in order to be definitely interpreted in that way. Without that, it's quite ambiguous.

Comment: @DanielRoseman What if I omit comma before "like" in the second sentence? Does it still sound ambiguous?